# Clean main Activity after device get sleep

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Actually, I have developed my Android Application version 10(2.33) but I  found a problem with this, when I run the Application on mobile it works fine but after sometime Mobile device goes into sleep mode and when I enable or unlock the device then observed that application display content which is filled by user get cleaned and content revert back when Orientation of device change. Sir please help me in this regards thanks in advance. I also bind source code for onCretae Method.

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView lstMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstMain);
    btnSetting =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSetting);
    btnCheck = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCheckStatus);
    btnabout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnabout);
    imgUserAdmin = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgUserAdmin);
    btnCheck.setOnClickListener(buttonhandler);
    btnSetting.setOnClickListener(buttonhandler);
    btnExit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
    btnLocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddSelLocation);
    btnLocation.setOnClickListener(buttonhandler);
    btnExit.setOnClickListener(buttonhandler);        
    startService(new Intent(this,SmsService.class));
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConstantClass.SMS_RECEIVED);
    registerReceiver(smsSend.sms_send,smsSend.getSentIntentFilter());
    registerReceiver(smsSend.sms_delivered,smsSend.getDeliveredFilter());
    registerReceiver(receivedSms,filter);
   lstMain.setOnItemClickListener(lstMainClick);

    dba.Open();
    String str = "SELECT " + DataBaseAdapter.Key_UserID + " FROM " + ConstantClass.dbName[0] + " WHERE " +
    DataBaseAdapter.Key_MBID + " = ?";
     id = dba.CurrentWorkingCoordinator(DataBaseAdapter.Key_SendCoord, 1);
     if(!Integer.toString(id).equals(ConstantClass.isCrdDiffer))
         ConstantClass.isAuditrequestSend=true;
     if(ConstantClass.isAuditrequestSend==false)
        btnCheck.setText("Checking..");
    String c = null;
    if(id!=0){
    Cursor admin =dba.ExecuteSelect(str, id);
    if (admin!=null)
        admin.moveToFirst();
    if(admin.getCount()>0){
         c = admin.getString(admin.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_UserID));
        if(c.equals("A")){
            ConstantClass.has_authority = "A";
            imgUserAdmin.setImageResource(R.drawable.admin);
        }else
        imgUserAdmin.setImageResource(R.drawable.admingreen);
    }
    if(ConstantClass.SelectCord.equals("All")){
        btnCheck.setEnabled(false);
        btnSetting.setEnabled(false);
        String dev="000000";
        curMain = dba.SelectDeviceOnId(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevID, dev);
        /*cursor = dba.getCoord(1);
        if (cursor.getCount()>0){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            ConstantClass.address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_MbNo)).toString();
        }*/
        startManagingCursor(curMain);
        if(curMain.getCount()>0){
            curMain.moveToFirst();
            adpt = new customCursorAdapter(this,curMain);  
            lstMain.setAdapter(adpt);           
        }

    }else{
    curMain = dba.SelFromDeviceStorage(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevCoordId,id); 
    cursor = dba.getCoord(1);
    if (cursor.getCount()>0){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        ConstantClass.address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_MbNo)).toString();
    }
    startManagingCursor(curMain);
    if(curMain.getCount()>0){
        curMain.moveToFirst();
        adpt = new customCursorAdapter(this,curMain);  
        lstMain.setAdapter(adpt);           
            }
        }
    }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        dlg = new ExceptionDialog(this,"Zigbee Activity",ex.getMessage());
        dlg.show();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your activity in your manifest.

```
android:configChanges="orientation">
```

Also read Greg's link :-p